# Copy Entity Framework stored procedure result list to another list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a situation in my ASP.NET MVC application where my stored procedure is returning one type of object `ObjectResult<pHNWReconHistory_Result>` and my view uses another type of object with exact same structure `List<HNWReconHistory>`.

I have to use this other type as the code is built in that way only. I am able to copy the data from source to target list but it is taking too much time. Is there any way to copy data quickly? I have about 80k rows and its taking 5+ mins to create new list using foreach.

I have tried AutoMapper and LINQ to create a copy but both were not very fruitful as they were also taking more or less same time. Is there a better way to achieve this?

This is how I am doing it currently:

```
var data = db.pHNWReconHistory();
            
foreach (pHNWReconHistory_Result scul in data)
{
    HNWReconHistory hNWReconHistory = new HNWReconHistory
    {
        AccountName = scul.Account_Name,
        Portcode = scul.Portfolio_Code,
        SubAdvisor = scul.Sub_Advisor,
        CurrencyName = scul.Base_Currency,
        SecurityType = scul.Security_Type,
        SecuritySymbol = scul.Security_Symbol,
        Description = scul.Description,
        Security = scul.Security
    };

    vm.HNWReconHistoryList.Add(empDTO);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "were not very fruitful" did you have errors ? badly implemented it ? To slow for your taste ?

Comment: they were slow too

Comment: Well creating a copy cannot will be slow and that's what you need so speed is that you have. You can however parallelize this with multithread but it wont be an insane gain. Typically you cut time by 20%~50% depending on the many factors. If you just want 1 list you should use a shared interface and implement in both so you can cast to the interface to read the value.

Answer (score 0):

By using `Add` with `foreach` yes, it is a very slow process that I've experienced it also. A much faster result was `AddRange`. So prepare your list first and then do  `vm.HNWReconHistoryList.AddRange(newList)`.